# While loop/ for loop: How to print together results from different loops?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am having trouble writing the right code to print (T, sol_h).

sol_h is an np. array with the same size as T.

When printing (T) you get something similar to:

```
0.00
5.00
10.00
15.02
20.03
25.05
30.06
35.07
40.08
45.08
50.10
...
```

The code below only prints T:

```
start_time = time.time() 
impact_time= sol.t_events[3] # = 154.75 s  

sol_h = sol.y[0]
# solution from a previous function

While True:
    current_time = time.time() 
    elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
    T = '{:.02f}'.format(elapsed_time)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(T)
    
    if elapsed_time > impact_time:
        print ("Impact has occured")
        break
print (Loop has finished)
```

This code only prints h:

```
for h in sol_h:
    print(h)

# Result
0.0
242.18277624405562
1016.2986152430877
2397.4567532549913
4463.395396560339
7289.10447523776
...
```

Is there a way to print (T, h), so that it looks like this?

```
0.00, 0.0
5.00, 242.18277624405562
10.00, 1016.2986152430877
15.02, 2397.4567532549913
20.03, 4463.395396560339
25.05, 7289.10447523776
...,   ...
```

I am open to change the whole code, to get the right print(T,h)

Comment: `T` isn't an array, it's a string containing the formatted elapsed time.

Comment: oh yes. that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that prints the time and calls `time.sleep()` inside the `for` loop

```
for h in sol_h:
    current_time = time.time() 
    elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
    T = '{:.02f}'.format(elapsed_time)
    print(T, h)

    time.sleep(5)

    if elapsed_time > impact_time:
        print ("Impact has occured")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I wanted was that at every 5 seconds, T to be printed alongside h. When I use the code you provided a single line of (T,h) was printed

Answer (score 0):

in print call to print T you can use end = ',', this will not cause a new line before next print.
See the following example

```
T = [0.00,5.00,10.00,15.00,20.00]
h = [0.00,242.18,1016.29,2397.45,4463.39,7289.10]
for index in range(len(T)):
     print(T[index],end=',')
     print(h[index])
```